# Xcode 7 beta 4 - Crashes on UI recording

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

While trying to do UI recording for my UI tests, the app crashed after 1 event that was not recorded. Looking into the crash report, I found this error:
    `UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): ancestorFinder is not being processed by childNodeFinders`

Anyone also getting this and maybe someone knows a fix for this?

Comment: File a bug report or it won't get fixed.

Comment: you might want to look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33484934/110530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's just life with beta software, did you try reinstalling Xcode 7 beta 4.

If it still doesn't work, might be a beta thing.

### Solution

Look forward to Xcode 7 beta 5

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, this seems a bug related to the absence of accessibility identifier on the item used to generate the event.
If your UI is created using the Interface Builder, [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484934/110530) is certainly relevant.

If, like me, your are creating your UI object programmatically, you can set a value to the `accessibilityIdentifier` property of your UI element (e.g. a `UIButton`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that Apple are aware of but require more details to debug it.  Please see this link for info:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/10623