# Xcode 7 Beta 6 Pre-release App won't launch (in simulator)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7-beta6

I'm trying to get UI testing set up for my project - I encountered a crash with previous betas. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713931/xcode-7-beta-4-crashes-on-ui-recording) stack overflow question if you are interested)

Anyway, I was quite thrilled to try it with Xcode 7 Beta 5. I created a simple Single Page app, added a text field and button, and ran it in Simulator. The simulator loads but the app doesn't get installed.

I've tried it in different simulators, all iOS 9 - same behavior in all of them.

Anyone else see this behavior? Am I missing something?

Comment: Quit Xcode. Clean the caches. Restart the computer.

Comment: Also, try deleting all simulators and creating them again. I often find I have to do that when there's an update.

Comment: Quitting Xcode, and restarting the computer did the trick.

Comment: That's my experience too. Glad it worked!