# Can't run UI Testing on older project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to add and run UI Automation tests with Xcode 7 on an older project.
Here's what I did:

1. Added a new UI Testing target
2. Changed the compiler version of that target to Default compiler (Apple LLVM 7.0)
3. Recorded a test using the iPhone 6 Plus iOS9 simulator (worked like a charm)

Now, when I try to run the recorded test I get the following error:

> failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "No target
>   application path specified via test configuration:
>   
>                       testBundleURL:file:///xxxxxxxxxxx/PlugIns/PageonceUITests.xctest/
>                   productModuleName:(null)
>                         testsToSkip:(null)
>                          testsToRun:(null)
>                  reportResultsToIDE:no
>                   sessionIdentifier:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fc818d181a0> 7045B650-CDAF-4EC9-9738-83F78E1514D8
>          pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
>           disablePerformanceMetrics:no  treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
>                     baselineFileURL:(null)
>               targetApplicationPath:(null)
>           targetApplicationBundleID:(null)

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to be complaining about "Target to be tested" field selected while adding UI Test Target.Does your "Target Application" property under UI Test Target -> General tab correctly shows your main app selected?
A happy config would look like this,

```
2015-10-04 17:30:50.960 XCTRunner[22941:4703128] Found configuration <XCTestConfiguration: 0x7fbf3050c8b0>

testBundleURL:file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fxeyzrynjcscxzaxjvmnormcjhbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/APPUITests.xctest/
              productModuleName:APPUITests
                    testsToSkip:(null)
                     testsToRun:(null)
             reportResultsToIDE:YES
              sessionIdentifier:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fbf30503430> B324DF9D-769F-4217-901F-24482A719005
     pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
      disablePerformanceMetrics:no
treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
                baselineFileURL:(null)
          targetApplicationPath:/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP-fxeyzrynjcscxzaxjvmnormcjhbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app
      targetApplicationBundleID:com.bundle.appBundle.app.dev
               reportActivities:no
```

Comment: I had the very same issue and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276523/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-when-running-uitesting-with-xcode-7?answertab=votes#tab-top) solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Its might be due to some issue with your **Target** settings.

Try the following.

1. Delete the existing target .
2. Create a new Target by selecting "**iOS UI Testing bundle**" again.
3. Then link your test files one by one.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by not using a Legacy build location as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32658990/901334

If I use "Legacy", UI tests can be recorded, but fail when I try to run them. Using "Unique" as setting and they work fine. (this can be reproduced with a new project)

Xcode → Preferences → Locations → Derived Data → Advanced... → [x] Unique

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a physical iPad. 
When I finally deleted the app and all of its data and then shut down and rebooted the device the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You must add in your **UITest target**,  in the relative "**Build Settings**" section, a custom "**User-Defined settings**" property:

[image]

with the keys:

`TEST_TARGET_NAME` : `YourTargetName`
`USES_XCTRUNNER`: `YES` (optional)

Now you're able to run your UI Tests.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have the UI test files in the unit test target, make sure the file is in the correct target.