# Xcode UITesting crashes

Tags: xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing

Anyone familiar with the following issue when generating UI tests?

```
Crashed Thread:        26  Dispatch queue: XCUIRecorder_iOS.processingQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

The problem lies in the fact that when trying to press a control, Xcode suddenly crashes.

I know this is a widely known error, however, any solutions so far?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I managed to find a workaround for this problem.

In my case I had a collection view with lots of cells in it, I was trying to test the interaction with the cells and as soon as I was tapping a cell Xcode will crash with the same error. I've looked into the crash logs and after this

`Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY`

I was able to find a snapshopArray of the view tree, in my case it was looking like this:

```
"Application 0x7fb0d39ce270: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: 'Workout'",
"Window 0x7fb0d643cda0: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}",
"Other 0x7fb0d58d9850: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}",
"Other 0x7fb0d40c27f0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}",
"Other 0x7fb13a249920: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}",
"Other 0x7fb138762330: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}",
"Other 0x7fb0d5e1b830: {{0.0, 20.0}, {320.0, 497.0}}",
"CollectionView 0x7fb0d401ddd0: {{0.0, 64.0}, {320.0, 453.0}}",
"Cell 0x7fb13a6419e0: {{52.5, 96.0}, {43.0, 43.0}}, label: '2'",
"Other 0x7fb138701770: {{52.5, 96.0}, {43.0, 43.0}}",
"StaticText 0x7fb0d393d500: {{52.5, 96.0}, {43.0, 43.0}}, label: '2'"
```

You dont need to pay too much attention and you can see that the CollectionView object doesnt have an accessibilityLabel. I immediately opened my storyboard and guess what, I didnt had Accessibility enabled for my collection view. I enabled it and added an identifier and a label. Run the UI Test recording again and guess what: BINGO! no more crashes!

Your case might be different but always check if your views have the accessibility enabled and have of course a label and an identifier set in place.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a bug related to accessibility, you might want to look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33961191/1844385).
My workaround was to programmatically set the value of the `accessibilityIdentifier` property of the control that generates the crash.